# Selecting different elements of an R dataframe (one for each row, but possibly different columns) without using loops

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a `data.frame` of arbitrary dimensions (`n` by `p`). I want to extract a vector of length `n` from that `data.frame`, one element in the vector per row in the `data.frame`. However, the column in which each element lies may vary by row.  Is there a way to do this without loops?

For example, if I have the following (3x3) data frame, called say DATA

```
X   Y   Z
1  17  43
3   4   2
6   9   0
```

I want to extract one scalar value from DATA per row. I have a vector, call it column.list, c(1,3,1) (arbitrarily selected in this case) which gives the column index for the elements I want, where the kth element of column.list is the column index for row k in DATA. How do I do this without loops? I want to avoid loops because I am using this repeatedly in a simulation study that will take a lot of running time even without loops, and the row number might be 100,000 or so.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by indexing your data.frame with a matrix. The first column indicates row, the second indicates column. So if you do

```
column.list <- c(1,3,1) 
DATA[cbind(1:nrow(DATA), column.list)]
```

You will get

```
[1] 1 2 6
```

as desired. If you mix across columns of different classes, all the variable will be coerced to the most accommodating data type.

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thank you